# Openpyxl - Retrieving "Special" Formatting Information From Cell

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am struggling with reading in Openpyxl files into python, I have a load of USA zip codes in some columns (you never know exactly which column will contain these) and have noticed that when I load the excel file Openpyxl removes the leading zeros. For example ZIP code 07075 becomes 7075 making it invalid.

I am wanting to simply open the excel file and save the contents into a CSV file, however as soon as I use cell.value the leading 0 is lost. I have had a play around in the CELL.py file of the Openpyxl package but I cannot figure it out.

the code where the leading zero is being lost at is:

`print(sheet["f2"].value)`

Any help would be appreciated. I have found a very old fix online but cannot implement it into the new version of the package. here - https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/70

UPDATE:
I have noticed that the column for the ZIP codes in Excel is formatted as "Special". Does anyone know how to access the special formatting of a cell in Openpyxl?

Comment: It's not openpyxl, a number does not include leading zeros. You may format a number with leading zeros in Excel e.g. so that 7057 looks like 07057 in the cell but the number to Excel is still 7057 and that is what openpyxl reads. Unless it's text then all characters should be retained as a text string.

Comment: I have added an update to the question. Unfortunately I will have no way of being able to edit files coming into the system in the future so I cannot manually change beforehand.

Comment: Its likely that the cells with Zip Codes are formatted as 'Custom' -> '00000' which Excel recognises as Special format 'Zip Code'. Its still just a number format. Are you considering converting to text? Remember the numbers still do not have leading zeros so converting Special format 07057 to text format will result in a string '7057'

Comment: Maybe your best bet is to load excel to Pandas dataframe, add the leading zeros to the required column(s) then save dataframe as csv.

Comment: hmmm yes, aware it just changes to 7057 annoyingly. However if I dont know which column will contain the ZIP codes I cant just add a 0 before it. I thought potentially I could get a formatting value or code to help recognise a specific 'special' format on the numbers?

Comment: You can check the individual cell number format, I expect  its 5 zeros so if cell A1 was a Zip # then **wb['Sheet1']["A1"].number_format = '00000'**

Comment: Use Python's "zfill" option before you write to the CSV.

Comment: Thanks moken I have gotten there with this trick!

Answer (score 0):

From what you are saying there is no way to determine which which column holds the Zip Codes in any given excel book. Therefore you are trying to determine which column from the number format, so no headers either?

Anyway here is an example that might help. It loads the excel file to Pandas checks for columns with numeric values only between 3 and 5 chars in length and then pads out that column with zeros so all numbers have length 5 before saving as a csv file.
Of course if you do have a better way to determine which is the Zip Code column that method can be used instead.

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('zip_codes.xlsx', header=None)

numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
for col in numeric_columns:
    current_column = col + 1
    print("Numeric Column: " + str(current_column) +
          " or '" + str(get_column_letter(current_column)) + "'")
    min_num = df[col].values.min()
    length_of_lowest_number = len(str(min_num))
    print("Smallest number in column is " + str(min_num) + " with length: " +
          str(length_of_lowest_number))
    max_num = df[col].values.max()
    length_of_highest_number = len(str(max_num))
    print("Largest number in column is " + str(max_num) + " with length: " +
          str(length_of_highest_number))
    if length_of_highest_number <= 5 and length_of_lowest_number >= 3:
        print("Pad all numbers to length 5 with leading zeros")
        df[col] = df[col].apply('{:0>5}'.format)
    else:
        print("Numbers do not appear to be Zip Codes")

print("Write dataframe to csv")
df.to_csv('output_file.csv', header=None, index=None)
```

A example Excel file where Column C has the Zip Codes formatted as 'Zip Codes' as above and some other random numerical columns F & G.
[image]

The CSV file

"HOLTSVILLE, NY",HOLTSVILLE,00501,NY,SUFFOLK,34459920,1
"AGAWAM, MA",AGAWAM,01001,MA,HAMPDEN,16115163,2
"AMHERST, MA",AMHERST,01002,MA,HAMPSHIRE,51768205,3
"AMHERST, MA",AMHERST,01003,MA,HAMPSHIRE,1918327,4
"AMHERST, MA",AMHERST,01004,MA,HAMPSHIRE,10742219,5
"BARRE, MA",BARRE,01005,MA,WORCESTER,1404282,6
"BELCHERTOWN, MA",BELCHERTOWN,01007,MA,HAMPSHIRE,19860169,7
"BLANDFORD, MA",BLANDFORD,01008,MA,HAMPDEN,29948181,8
"BONDSVILLE, MA",BONDSVILLE,01009,MA,HAMPDEN,408326,9
"BRIMFIELD, MA",BRIMFIELD,01010,MA,HAMPDEN,14092675,10